# Using sklearn with complex values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, complex-numbers

I am trying to perform a kmeans in Python using scikit-learn. The thing is my data are complex values and Python doesn't like it.

Is there any mean to use sklearn with complex values ?

Comment: It isn't directly handled by scikit-learn, just split into real and imaginary parts? The only downside is that you'll end up with twice as many dimensions, though if that's not a problem this should do the job just fine

Comment: Try different representation for your complex numbers, ex. multiply number each by its `complex conjugate` which gives you a `real number`, by this way you keep dependency some how encoded into a real number, this might improve the result of k-means, or find the magnitude of your complex number, `L2 (norm`).

Comment: You can also use the `np.real` method (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.real.html) to extract the real part of a complex number

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what those imaginary numbers represent to you.

If you want to cluster them in a certain sense you have to define a metric.
You can choose to perform a clustering based on theyr real and imaginary coordinates or you can use the absolute value as value for the clustering. Otherwise you can convert the imaginary representation in the polar form and so cluster them based on the modulus and angular argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Actually the imaginary numbers doesn't represent anything in particular to me. Indeed, I am performing a k-means on the eigenvalues of the laplacian matrix of my dataset. I tried to use the absolute value. The thing is the more the number of clusters is important, the greater the inertia will be. Then, I have an increasing inertia with the elbow method. Is it normal ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. Actually the imaginary numbers doesn't represent anything in particular to me. Indeed, I am performing a k-means on the eigenvalues of the laplacian matrix of my dataset. I tried to use the absolute value. The thing is the more the number of clusters is important, the greater the inertia will be. Then, I have an increasing inertia with the elbow method. Is it normal ?